# How to add required true on collection_select type field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have already tried to add required=> true and :prompt=>"select..." on the collection_select field, but every time I get syntax error. How to solve this error which is below.

```
.field
  = f.label "Receiver"
  = f.collection_select(:receiver_admin_id, 
        Admin.agent_and_admin(current_admin.id, current_admin.parent_master_agent_id), 
        :id, 
        :agent_name, 
        :prompt => 'Select receiver', 
        {multiple: true}), 
      :required => true
```

```
  = f.collection_select(:receiver_admin_id, 
        Admin.agent_and_admin(current_admin.id, current_admin.parent_master_agent_id), 
        :id, 
        :agent_name, 
        :prompt => 'Select receiver', 
        {multiple: true, required: true})
```

```
  = f.collection_select(:receiver_admin_id, 
        Admin.agent_and_admin(current_admin.id, current_admin.parent_master_agent_id), 
        :id, 
        :agent_name, 
        :prompt => 'Select receiver',
        {}, 
        {multiple: true}), 
      :required => true
```

```
  = f.collection_select :receiver_admin_id, 
        Admin.agent_and_admin(current_admin.id, current_admin.parent_master_agent_id), 
        :id, 
        :agent_name, 
        :prompt => 'Select receiver', 
        {multiple: true}, 
        :required => true
```

Comment: please update a error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
  = f.collection_select :receiver_admin_id, Admin.agent_and_admin(current_admin.id, current_admin.parent_master_agent_id), :id, :agent_name, {prompt: 'Select receiver'}, {multiple: true, required: true}
```

Comment: I have also tried this, but the problem is that when I don't select or choose any one of a select item that time alert not working,  like " please select ... "

Answer (score 0):

Your were close almost everytime :) From the docs [in the rails guide](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) you have:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Using the form helpers (`f.`) mean that the object (first argument) is taken care of so you're left with:

`method, collection, value_method, text_method, options, html_options`

Both the multiple and required need to be in the html_options so:

```rb
= f.collection_select(:receiver_admin_id, Admin.agent_and_admin(current_admin.id, current_admin.parent_master_agent_id), :id, :agent_name, { :prompt => 'Select receiver' }, multiple: true, :required => true)
```